# PHPUnit + Selenium, close browser when error

Tags: php, selenium, browser, phpunit, exit

I'm doing testing in PHPUnit+Selenium (using PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase) and I need to do something to close browser even if the test result on error. Let's see, I've done this test:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected $fail;
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*chrome');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('http://www.google.com/');
        $this->assertTitle($this->fail->value());
    }
}
?>
```

Which result on error caused by:

```
$this->assertTitle($this->fail->value());
```

Because there is not value in **$fail** and then the test finishes getting an error. The problem is that the browser remains open in Selenium. How can I force to close browser from Selenium?

Thx in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940214/keeping-selenium-browser-open-with-phpunit-selenium

Comment: @AlexandruG. This is not what I'm looking for... The browser stays open and I want to close it.

Comment: The idea of my previous comment was to check if you enabled `browserSessionReuse` and forgot about it. You could also try with `$this->stop()`.

Comment: @AlexandruG. Already tried it. It does nothing because the code crashes before.

Comment: Try adding `$this->shareSession(false);` before `$this->open('http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: @AlexandruG. still nothing :(