# how to reuse selenium session in PHP?

Tags: php, session, selenium

I have problem to reuse selenium session object in 2 function of my code. how can i do that?
first function called and it's show the result. then second function called from html post method. how can run selenium in second function with first function session? 
thanks

```
$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");
$webdriver->get("http://AAA.AAA");
//here with some method i store picture of captcha to show 
echo '<form  method="post" action="process.php">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Enter value of picture
            <img src="thumb.jpeg">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="captcha" dir="ltr">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button class="submit">Send</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>';
```

And process.php it's like this ( second function )

```
$webdriver->findElementBy("id","username")->sendKeys("XXX");
$webdriver->findElementBy("id","password")->sendKeys("YYYY");
$webdriver->findElementBy("id","captcha")->sendKeys($_POST['captcha']);    
$webdriver->findElementBy("id","submit")->click();
```

but $webdriver in second function is not defined, and it must have same session id with $webdriver in first function
How Can I Do That?

Comment: If you can get the session id before clicking Submit button, jQuery or similar can append a hidden element to the form, value of which could be the session ID. Then on `process.php` check value of the POST var value.

Comment: This may help in concept http://www.ontestautomation.com/using-the-page-object-design-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver/ even though the code language is Java

Comment: no i can't get the session. and i'm sure it's not work, selenium session is object with resource id . it's not possible to send this with hidden value

Comment: Please see accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940214/keeping-selenium-browser-open-with-phpunit-selenium

Answer (score 1):

[keeping selenium browser open with phpunit/selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940214/keeping-selenium-browser-open-with-phpunit-selenium) shows a Webdriver option -browserSessionReuse

Suggest reading all answers on that page, it may serve helpful.